# Sybase PowerBuilder Pipeline question

Tags: database, sybase, powerbuilder, pipeline

I am very new to PowerBuilder. I have a question regarding the data transfer from one table to another using Pipeline. 
The source table has one addition field, lets say 'transfer'. Initially this column has value 0. After the data has been transferred from source table to destination table, I need to update the source table's column 'transfer' to 1. I am unable to figure out, do i need to create a new pipeline to update the source table again? or what is the way? 
I am using following for pipeline. I will appreciate any help.

```
lp_Create.DataObject  =  "p_create_tableA"
li_rc  =   lp_Create.Start(lt_Source,  sqlca,  dw_errors)
If  li_rc  <>  1  Then
    MessageBox("Some error","Error  return  code:  "  +  string(li_rc))
End  if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the pipeline isn't about creating values for your "source" table that aren't being copied from somewhere. Usually, you'd want a DataStore for that. However, if you've got exclusive access to the table (no other users, no other processes or triggers), this would be one of the few cases in PowerBuilder where I'd recommend an embedded SQL statement with something like:

```
UPDATE <table> SET transfer = 1
```

If you *don't* have exclusive access to the source table (and someone/something else can be writing new records to it after your pipeline but before you update the transfer flag), then it's a whole other problem, which probably isn't worth going into if you're new to PowerBuilder and this isn't your situation.

Good luck,

Terry.